# On Window resize, html table columns

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I am working on making modifications to a website. I have copied the code of an html file with table and inserted my php code to generate the table. I am having issue with the table rendering on the page on window resize. Attached are the links for how the table looks when window is resize.

[image]

On window resize, my columns are becoming rows.

[image]

Table when viewed in full browser

It's a dynamically generated table using php. Here's the code: Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
<DIV class="section-container">
    <DIV id="layout" class="rsp_kvheader">
        <!-- custom_1 -->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div align="left">
                        <TABLE style="background-color: #eee; background-image: url(http://eworksxl.web.com/repo/images/kv1.jpg);;;;;;;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" class="fullwidth" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed;">
                            <TBODY>
                                <TR>
                                    <TD align="center"></TD>
                                </TR>
                            </TBODY>
                        </TABLE>
                    </div>
                    <br style="clear:both;">
                    <!-- ADD CUSTOM BLOCK --> 
                    <div align="center" >
                        <table   border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: auto;">
                            <tr>
                                <td  align="center" valign="top" >
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <DIV><img width="2000" title="" assetid="122087963" src="../../image/timesheet_1.jpg" height="550" style="width:2000px;height:370px;" border="0" alt="" mce_src="/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=4C8960FFB6D8F307F69627A62EC4099A?id=122087963&_dt=1488490190826" selectedfileurl="../../files/timesheet_1.jpg"></DIV>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <br style="clear:both;">
                    <div align="center" >
                        <table   border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%" style="table-layout: auto;">
                            <tr>
                                <td  align="center" valign="top" >
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <TABLE width="80%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: auto;">
                                            <TBODY>
                                                <TR>
                                                    <TD align="left">
                                                        <DIV class="rsp_content section Content-1Column-Text">
                                                            <H1><?php echo $fname." ".$lname ?></H1>
                                                            <div class="container">
                                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="table-layout: auto;" width="80%">
                                                                        <thead>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center" width="5%">#</th>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center" width="19%">Date</th>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center" width="19%">Day</th>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center" width="19%">Hours</th>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </thead>
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <form action ="timesheet.php" method="post">
                                                                                <?php
                                                                                    $today = date("Y-m-d");
                                                                                    // echo $today;

                                                                                    $first_day = date("Y-m-1");
                                                                                    // echo $first_day;

                                                                                    $date = $first_day;

                                                                                    $i=0;

                                                                                    $table = $empid."_user";
                                                                                    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($today)) {
                                                                                                    // echo "$date\n";
                                                                                                    $newDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($date)); 
                                                                                                    $day = date("l", strtotime($date));
                                                                                                    $i++;

                                                                                                    $sql_statement="select hours from $table where work_date='$newDate'";
                                                                                                    $sql_result= $conn->query($sql_statement);
                                                                                                    // $row=mysqli_fetch_row($sql_result);
                                                                                                    // $hour_entered=$row[0];
                                                                                                    // echo $hour_entered;

                                                                                                    if(($sql_result->num_rows) > 0){
                                                                                                    $row=mysqli_fetch_row($sql_result);
                                                                                                    $hour_entered=$row[0];
                                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                                        $hour_entered=null;
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                    ?>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <?php if($day=="Sunday" || $day=="Saturday"){
                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                    <td style="color:orange; border: double 3px black;" align="center" width="5%">
                                                                                        <?php echo $i ?>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td style="color:orange; border: double 3px black;" align="center" width="19%">
                                                                                        <?php echo $newDate ?> 
                                                                                        <input type="hidden" name="dates[]" value="<?php echo $newDate?>"> 
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td style="color:orange; border: double 3px black;" align="center" width="19%">
                                                                                        <?php echo $day ?>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <?php
                                                                                        if($hour_entered!=null){
                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                    <td align="center" style="color:orange; border: double 3px black;" width="19%">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="hours[]" id="hour_input" value="<?php echo $hour_entered ?>" style="text-align:center" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
                                                                                        <!-- <?php echo $hour_entered ?> -->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <?php   
                                                                                        }else{
                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                    <td align="center" style="color:orange; border: double 3px black;" width="19%">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="hours[]" style="text-align:center" value="0" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
                                                                                        <!-- <?php echo $hour_entered ?> -->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <?php
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <?php
                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                    ?>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td align="center" width="5%">
                                                                                        <?php echo $i ?>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td align="center" width="19%">
                                                                                        <?php echo $newDate ?> 
                                                                                        <input type="hidden" name="dates[]" value="<?php echo $newDate?>"> 
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td align="center" width="19%">
                                                                                        <?php echo $day ?>
                                                                                        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="dates[]" <?php echo $day?> > -->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <?php
                                                                                        if($hour_entered!=null){
                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                    <td align="center" width="19%">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="hours[]" id="hour_input" value="<?php echo $hour_entered ?>" style="text-align:center" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
                                                                                        <!-- <?php echo $hour_entered ?> -->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <?php   
                                                                                        }else{
                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                    <td align="center" width="19%">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="hours[]" style="text-align:center" value="0" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
                                                                                        <!-- <?php echo $hour_entered ?> -->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <?php
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <?php
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    ?>
                                                                                <?php
                                                                                    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    ?>
                                                                                <!-- </tr> -->
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td colspan="4" align="right">
                                                                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </form>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </DIV>
                                                    </TD>
                                                </TR>
                                            </TBODY>
                                        </TABLE>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <br style="clear:both;">
                    <div align="center" >
                        <table   border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
                            <tr>
                                <td  align="center" valign="top" >
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <TABLE style="width: 100%; background-color: #414141;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <TBODY>
                                                <TR>
                                                    <TD style="text-align: center;">
                                                        <SPAN style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
                                                            <SPAN style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
                                                                <BR><BR>Share This Page:<BR>
                                                                <div id='webcom-component-socialmediashare-17657540220791720'></div>
                                                            </SPAN>
                                                        </SPAN>
                                                    </TD>
                                                </TR>
                                            </TBODY>
                                        </TABLE>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <br style="clear:both;"> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- END-OF custom_1 -->
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: too many nested <table></table>. Use one <table> the rest should be col <tr> and rows <td>. also,  don't use table-layout: fixed; (leave it Auto)..

Comment: Thanks, will try it! The same the case with multiple pages! Will work on them.